# Android browser url from edittext

Tags: android, browser

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("test");
    alert.setMessage("test");
    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      // Do something with value!
        String link = input.getText().toString();
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri
        .parse(link)));
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });
```

what I want is the browser to open on what the user inputted in the edittext before clicking Ok ..

currently the app force closes

Comment: Do you have a copy of the exception stack dump?

Comment: I found the mistake and fixed it, nvm. THANKS. u need http in the first :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the mistake and fixed it, nvm. THANKS. u need http in the first :D

The mistake was that you need `http://` at the beginning to open a browser using `Action_View`